PyCharm Allowing Selecting Empty Space
Suddenly, my PyCharm IDE started allowing me to blocks of text, instead of selecting by line.
Screenshot Selecting Empty Sections
I tried select multiple lines of my code, but instead of selecting the lines between the two endpoints, it selected specifically a box between those endpoints (see image). I believe this is just a setting that was likely changed by pressing a hotkey accidentally, but I do not know which setting it is.

This is normally triggered by pulling with middle mouse pressed. You might be able to find out more on your own by looking into that section.
